# How to hide a specific value from "select option"?

Tags: php, sql, select

I have a select box in a php script that get values from sql db to place in a select dropdown box.

My problem is: I want to hide only one item value from my db that shows on this dropdown.

Inside dropdown box I have 3 values: folder number 1 - folder number 2 - folder number 3

I don't want to show "folder number 3" and I can't delete it from my db. I just need to hide on this select box.

my script:

`<select name="upload_dir" id="upload_dir" >
 <?php echo $upload_dirs?> // This PHP get item value from my SQL DB
 </select>`

I have like 10 php pages: user.php, edit.php, admin.php etc... I just want to hide it on user.php so I can't delete from db or hide for all, I can only hide for user.php.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Any issue in changing the select query that returns this list?

Answer (score 4):

You can update your query to not include folder number 3

```
select * from table where folder_number != 3
```

or

```
select * from table where folder_number not in (3)
```

or after getting the result from the query do this

```
foreach($folder_number as $key => $value){ 
   if($value['folder_number'] != 3){ 
      $upload_dirs .= '<option value="'.$value['folder_number'].'">Folder Number '.$value['folder_number'].'</option>';
   }
}
```

Comment: I can't do it, because I need this folder in another part of script, I just don't need it on this specific page of script.
my script have like 10 pages, edit.php, user.php, admin.php etc..
I don't want to show this value only on user.php

Comment: check my additional code. the answer of @Teneff is also correct

Comment: sorry but I'm newbie on it. my line should be this : 

<select name="upload_dir" id="upload_dir" >
            <?php echo $upload_dirs foreach($folder_number as $key => $value){ if($value['folder_number'] != folder number 3) Hidden; }
?>
 </select>

Comment: just do the above code i gave you for the foreach to replace your own code. instead of $upload_dirs. = '<option....  change it to echo '<option....

Answer (score 2):

yoc can either exclude it from the SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM folders WHERE folder_name != "folder number 3"
```

or remove it from the array:

```
foreach ($upload_dirs as $key=> $dir) {
    if ($dir == "folder number 3") {
        unset($upload_dirs[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to do it, but I need this folder for edit.php and admin.php, I just want to hide it from user.php

Comment: @EduardoTelles you can create new array `$user_upload_dirs = $upload_dirs` and do it only in `user.php` and use `$upload_dirs` in the other pages